# Reloading a page with parameters

Tags: php, javascript, page-refresh

I have a page showing a random picture on each reload. This page only displays if a number is passed through $_GET (represents a user profile). To go to the next random picture I'd like a submit button to simply reload the page. However, I'm hitting two snags:

- In PHP using the `header` function produces the infamous "headers already sent by" error. Plus the user is redirected because no parameter is passed.
- In Javascript, a `location.reload` does reload the page but, again, the parameter is missing leading to the same result.

So my question is whether it is possible in Javascript to reload a page with a parameter? Or do you know of another solution?

Edit: Did some tests with an alert box and the url shows up as it appears in the adress bar. No idea why the parameter isn't being passed.

Answer (score 2):

You should wonder why you receive the `headers already sent` error. It is usually because your flow is incorrect. Make sure you handle your `PHP` before you generate the output. Check for the submitted form at the top of your code - and safely redirect without executing anything else. Should solve your problem.

Comment: As explained below @Berry Langerak's answer, there's a couple of `require_once` lines that will be difficult to move elsewhere. I've tried using `header` at the very start but no success so far.

Answer (score 2):

In another topic i found that

`window.location.replace(window.location.href)`

will keep the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> In PHP using the header function produces the infamous "headers already sent by" error.

That's simple enough: move the code that does the header( ) call up to the top (before any other output). "Headers already sent" is infamous, but also incredibly easy to solve.

> In Javascript, a location.reload does reload the page but, again, the parameter is missing leading to the same result.

Then pass it along? This should work, I think?

```
window.location( window.location.toString( ) );
```

Comment: Just tested this again with the ´toString´ as a variant. The result is the same and it's as if the parameter isn't being passed. The check near the top of the page is this: `isset($_GET['param']) && intval($_GET['param']) > 0`. As for the header error, this is most likely caused by a couple of `require_once` lines at the near top which do things like initialize the user and database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `location.reload` the page, you can use `document.location` to redirect the page to the same page with a parameter passed through GET. For example,

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['user_id'];
    echo "<script type='text/js'>
          document.location='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."&id=".$id."';
          </script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I might as well post this as it's been a pain getting something working through javascript and PHP and I don't have enough time to get something in ajax working. A simple workaround is to simply specify the parameter in the action attribute of the form (special markup is from smarty).

```
   <form Method="POST" ACTION="my_page.php?param={$smarty.get.i}">
          <!-- PHP: If ( isset($_POST['next']) ) do SQL ... -->
          <input type="submit" name="like" value="I like">
          <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" >
   </form>
```